# Incorrect syntax near Parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, C# and SQL Server database.

The T-SQL command works just fine if I replace the parameter with a concrete value.

I get this error on the last line of code:

> Incorrect syntax near '@Collection1'.

My code:

```
string myCommandString = "select Name, Collection, Text from List_Card @Collection1";
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myCommandString, myConnection);
SqlDataAdapter myydata = new SqlDataAdapter();

if (comboBox1.Text != "")
{
    string1 = "where Collection IN (select Shortcut from Collections where Collection Like '" + comboBox1.Text + "')";
}
else 
{
    string1 = ""; 
}

myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Collection1", string1));
myydata.SelectCommand = myCommand;

myConnection.Open();
DataTable myytab = new DataTable();
myydata.Fill(myytab);
```

Comment: this is definitely invalid syntax `string myCommandString = "select Name, Collection, Text from List_Card @Collection1";` what are you intending to accomplish putting `@Collection1` after the table name?

Comment: T-SQL is not a database engine

Comment: i have 'where' clause in @Collection. If user selects something in comboBox, i need that 'where' clause. If user doesnt select anything in comboBox, i dont need that 'where' clause.

Comment: Parameters are used to represent **values** to the database engine. It seems that you think that a parameter _substitutes_ a string in your command text. This is a common misconception.

Comment: The database engine in question is Microsoft **SQL Server**, while T-SQL (or Transact-SQL) is the "dialect" of SQL that is used by SQL Server for querying the database engine, and writing functions and procedures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

First, your myCommandString:

```
"select Name, Collection, Text from List_Card @Collection1"
```

That is invalid SQL syntax (what the error is you're getting). You're not doing anything with the parameter. You need to put it as a part of a `WHERE` clause, but you're not using that value.

Next, you're using the `SqlParameter` completely incorrectly. Check out [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_7) to see how to properly use it. The specific issue is that you don't assign a conditional SQL string as the second parameter. You need to conditionally append that to your query.

Finally, you should also wrap everything in `using` statements to properly dispose of the objects.

This should give you what you're looking for:

```
var myCommandString = "select Name, Collection, Text from List_Card ";

if (comboBox1.Text != "")
{
    myCommandString += " where Collection IN (select Shortcut from Collections where Collection Like '@Collection1')";
}

using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
using (var myCommand = new SqlCommand(myCommandString, myConnection))
{
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Collection1", string1));

    using (var myData = new SqlDataAdapter()) 
    {
        myData.SelectCommand = myCommand;
        myConnection.Open();

        var myytab = new DataTable();
        myydata.Fill(myytab);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters don't work like that. I'm guessing you want to have same query and then dynamically add where clause if user selects something. Unfortunately, you can't do it in a way that whole where clause is parameter. You can try something like this:

```
string myCommandString = @"select Name, Collection, Text from 
List_Card where Collection IN 
    (select Shortcut from Collections where Collection Like '%' + @collection + '%')";
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myCommandString, myConnection);
SqlDataAdapter myydata = new SqlDataAdapter();
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Collection1", comboBox1.Text));
myydata.SelectCommand = myCommand;
myConnection.Open();
DataTable myytab = new DataTable();
myydata.Fill(myytab);
```

Comment: Skipping disposal of IDisposable objects WILL lead to an unstable application, so, please, don't encourage it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the whole `WHERE` clause through a parameter. Parameters are allowed in place of ... well, parameters. If you want to add the `WHERE` clause based on a condition in your C# code, do this:

```
string myCommandString = "SELECT Name, Collection, Text FROM List_Card";
.
.
.

if (comboBox1.Text != "")
{
    myCommandString += " WHERE Collection IN (SELECT Shortcut FROM Collections WHERE Collection Like '" + comboBox1.Text + "')";
}
```

Also, it is super important to [dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern) of an object after its usage. The fastest way to do this is to eclose the code in a `using` statement. Finally, you should do your best to prevent [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection). You're already on the right track with this - in case of ADO.NET, adding `Parameter`s to your dynamic SQL queries is the right approach.

Since the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` are all IDisposable objects your code should look like this:

```
string myCommandString = "SELECT Name, Collection, Text FROM List_Card";

using (var  myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
using (var  myCommand = new SqlCommand(myCommandString, myConnection))
using (var  myydata = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    if (comboBox1.Text != "")
    {
        myCommandString += " WHERE Collection IN (SELECT Shortcut FROM Collections WHERE Collection Like @Collection1)";
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Collection1", comboBox1.Text));
    }

    myydata.SelectCommand = myCommand;
    myConnection.Open();
    DataTable myytab = new DataTable();
    myydata.Fill(myytab);
}
```

Comment: this is string concatenation, prone to sql injection. Please don't encourage unsafe and bad way of doing queries.

Comment: This is what the OP already has. The composition of the SQL statement is not a subject of that post, is it?